# Exchange mail flow rules for signatures

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-2013, outlook-2013

I've recently implemented an html signature using transport rules in exchange 2013, that appends given signature as a disclaimer to all emails from a given sender domain.

The problem is that the signature gets appended at the bottom of the entire email, including emails being replied to. Instead I would like the signature to appear only under each message sent.

The situation now:
email reply i sent
original email i received and am replying to
my signature

instead i want it to be:
email reply i sent
my signature
original email i received and am replying to

How do i do this, or are there any other better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using Exchange transport rules. You will need a third party product.

I use Exclaimer Signature Manager (manages Outlook signatures) and Exclaimer Mail Disclaimers (adds signatures at the transport level). I highly recommend them both.